# Working with nested data in Spark SQL / High order functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've recently started playing with Spark SQL (2.1) and I'm dealing with nested data.

Here is my schema:

```
 root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bb: string
 |    |-- bbb: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cca: string
 |    |    |    |-- ccb: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- member0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- member1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ccc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ccca: string
 |    |    |    |-- cccb: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cccc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cccca: string
 |    |    |    |-- ccccb: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I am trying to filter my data as follows: keep all the rows where c.ccc.key == 'data'

I found the very relevant function exists in databricks documentation. But I wonder if there is any similar outside of databricks notebooks?

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/higher-order-functions-lambda-functions.html#exists-array-t-function-t-v-boolean-boolean

I am willing to use sql or do it programatically, just not sure how as dataframes are not typed objects.

Reading this email thread http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-higher-order-functions-in-spark-SQL-be-pushed-upstream-td21703.html it seems that high order functions from databricks will be available for all soon. But I wonder if there is an intermediate solution anybody can share?

Comment: BTW with the "exists" function it would look like this " SELECT *,
EXISTS(c, item -> item.ccc.key == 'data')
FROM mytable"

Comment: can you share what you've tried? and also share some sample data to test with.

Comment: A row should look like this: `name | Map(k->v) | [(Map(kk->vv), Map(kkk->vvv, key->data), Map(kkk->vvv))]`

Comment: see the notebook example here from databricks (data is also available there) - https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/higher-order-functions-lambda-functions.html#exists-array-t-function-t-v-boolean-boolean Im looking for something that will act exactly as the "exists" function there

Comment: Essentially for each row in my table, I want to iterate over the array (field c), and if one of the elements in the array follows a certain condition, then I want to keep/mark this row.

Comment: seeing the schema you've provided in the question you must have a dataframe ready. Can you share some rows from the dataframe and also share how you want the output be?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot share the data itself as it's sensitive.

Comment: change the data to some dummy values then

Comment: This is too complicated... I am looking for databricks high order functions alternatives. if there are - it will work

Comment: http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-higher-order-functions-in-spark-SQL-be-pushed-upstream-td21703.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `dataframe` has `schema` as

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- member0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- member1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ccc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cccc: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Then you can write a `udf` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterUdf = udf((column: Seq[Row])=> column.map(x => x(1).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].keySet.contains("data")).contains(true))
```

which will scan every rows `c` column for `data` string is present or not and you can use the `udf` function in `filter` function as

```
df.filter(filterUdf(col("c")))
```

So finally you should have only the rows with `data` in `c.ccc.key`

Comment: @Maayan I guess you can upvote too :) If the post is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
some refinements:

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("contains_key", (field: Seq[Row], key: String, value: String) => field.exists(item => item.getAs[Map[String, String]]("ccc").get(key).getOrElse("").equals(value)))
```

Then it's accessible with spark sql:

```
spark.sql("select contains_key(c,"key","data") from mytable")
```